# Test a service in Spring with a Mock, What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking

I have a Spring-boot project, in witch I have controller, service and mapper layer. Now I want to test a service and I want to mock the mapper. I do it in this way:

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(Application.class)
@Transactional
public class SomeServiceTest extends   AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

@Mock
private AMapper aMapper;

@Autowired
@InjectMocks
AService aService;


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    executeSqlScript("classpath:insertSomeData.sql", false);
}

@Test
public void testMethod() throws Exception {
    //prepareSomeData
    aService.callMethod(someData);

    verify(aMapper).callTheRightMethod(rightObject);

}
```

And the service:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class AServiceImpl implements AService {

@Autowired
BMapper bMapper;

@Autowired
CMapper cMapper;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public SomeReturnObject callMethod(SomeData someData)throws Exception {
     //some execution to obtain aResult

     if(true){
       aMapper.callTheRightMethod(aResult);}
     else 
       aMapper.callWrongMethod(aResult);
}
```

Now when I execute the test the result is:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
aMapper.callTheRightMethod{..}
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

When i debug then I see that the method is called, but probably it's the wrong mapper (not the mocked). Have you some tips to figure out that issue?

Comment: Remove the `@Autowired` from `aService` in `SomeServiceTest`, it would work.

Comment: Yes this helped me to figure out the problems and solve it.  Tanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the mock interaction recording here. It should come before the actual invocation. It should be something like this.

```
Mockito.when(aMapper.callTheRightMethod(Mockito.any()).thenReturn(rightObject);
```

The flow should be like this. Firstly record the mocks, then perform actual invocation and finally verify the mock interactions. As above `@Autowire` is not needed for the test class. Please remove that too. Instead create a new instance of service class by passing some data through it's constructor. Hope this helps. Happy coding !

Comment: I had to made this for the other mappers but not for that where I will check the call of the method. Tanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand why would you start up spring context for testing just a service layer. **Test only one layer at a time.**

That's how I would address the problem. (If something does not compile, my apologies..writing from top of my head)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SomeServiceTest {

@Mock
private AMapper aMapper;

@InjectMocks
AService aService = new AService();

@Test
public void testMethod() throws Exception {
    // given
    Mockito.doReturn(aResult).when(aMapper).getAResult();
    // when
    aService.callMethod(someData);
    // then
    verify(aMapper).callTheRightMethod(rightObject);
}
```